# ELisp: How to execute several expressions in 'else' block?

Tags: emacs, elisp

How can I execute more than one expression in the `else` block of an `if` statement, when using ELisp?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need `progn` for this, as this is already the default behaviour:

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `if` <kbd>RET</kbd>

> if is a special form in `C source code'.
>
> (if COND THEN ELSE...)
>
> If COND yields non-nil, do THEN, else do ELSE...
>   Returns the value of THEN or the value of the last of the ELSE's.
>   **THEN must be one expression, but ELSE... can be zero or more expressions.**
>   If COND yields nil, and there are no ELSE's, the value is nil.

To re-use sindikat's example:

```el
(if (> 1 2)
    (message "True")
  (message "False")
  (message "I repeat, completely false"))
```

You would, of course, use `progn` if you wished to evaluate multiple expressions in the `THEN` form.

Answer (score 5):

[phils's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10333220/596361) is correct and idiomatic. If you want to execute several statements in the `else` block of `if`, and you're concerned only with Emacs Lisp, go with his answer.

In Emacs Lisp and Common Lisp when you want to perform multiple actions in sequence for [side effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29) (like change a variable, print something on screen, generally, anything that has nothing to do with function returning a value), and then return the value of only one of the expressions, you use [`progn`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sequencing.html#index-progn-560), [`prog1`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sequencing.html#index-prog1-561), or [`prog2`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sequencing.html#index-prog2-562). They all evaluate all the forms inside them, but return only the value of last, first and second expression respectively.

`(progn 1 2 3 4 5)` returns 5, `(prog1 1 2 3 4 5)` returns 1, `(prog2 1 2 3 4 5)` returns 2. This is clearly useless, because the point of evaluating forms inside `progn`, `prog1`, `prog2` is for side effects. So all of the following would print string `α`, `β`, `γ`, `δ` in [echo area](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Echo-Area.html) (and in [`*Messages*`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MessagesBuffer) buffer), but only one of the strings will be returned:

```
(progn (message "α") (message "β") (message "γ") (message "δ")) ; => "δ"
(prog1 (message "α") (message "β") (message "γ") (message "δ")) ; => "α"
(prog2 (message "α") (message "β") (message "γ") (message "δ")) ; => "β"
```

All 3 functions exist both in Emacs Lisp and Common Lisp. But what if you want to return the 3<sup>rd</sup> expression's value? There is no `prog3`. Combine existing ones! All of the following return `γ`:

```
(progn (message "α") (message "β") (prog1 (message "γ") (message "δ"))) ; => "γ"
(prog1 (progn (message "α") (message "β") (message "γ")) (message "δ")) ; => "γ"
(prog2 (message "α") (progn (message "β") (message "γ")) (message "δ")) ; => "γ"
(prog2 (message "α") (prog2 (message "β") (message "γ") (message "δ"))) ; => "γ"
```

In Common Lisp to group statements together and return only the last one's value in `if`, you would do:

```
(if t
    (progn (message "ε") (message "ζ"))
    (progn (message "η") (message "θ"))) ; returns ζ
(if nil
    (progn (message "ε") (message "ζ"))
    (progn (message "η") (message "θ"))) ; returns θ
```

In Emacs Lisp you still have to group statement in `then` block with `progn`, `prog1`, `prog2`, but you in `else` block you don't have to, thus phils's answer. In Emacs Lisp `(if nil 1 2 3)` would return 3, while in Common Lisp it would err with `too many parameters for special operator IF`.

*See also*: Section "[8.1.4 The 'progn' Special Form](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-lisp-intro/html_node/progn.html)" from "[Emacs Lisp Intro](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-lisp-intro/)".

Comment: this is not the best answer. it's ok to use progn but it's more readable to go with the fact that you're allowed more than one expression in the else. In fact elisp programmers often organize the whole construct deliberately around that fact (if you have a positive test where the success step is multiple steps then make a negative test where those steps are the else).

Comment: Depends on what you want to return.  If you want to return the value of the last expression, phils' answer or this one work.  If you want to return the value of the first expression prog1 works.  If you want to return the value of an arbitrary expression in a series, nest a prog1 inside the progn.